How to avoid races with process IDs when reading /proc
As I understand it, on Linux process IDs are reused, and also the only API for a lot of process-related stuff (e.g. finding child processes of a specific process) is /proc/<pid>/....
But don't these two facts mean that pretty much any process related code is open to race conditions? For example suppose I want to kill all my children. As far as I know the only way to do this is (pseudocode):
for pid in `/proc/*`:
  if parse_parent_field(read(`/proc/$pid/stat`)) == my_pid():
    kill(pid)

However doesn't this mean that there's a gap between reading the file and sending the kill signal where the process could end anyway and a new one could start with the same PID, meaning you accidentally kill the wrong process?
Maybe this is very unlikely in this scenario but I'm sure there are others where it isn't.
How do you deal with this properly? For example if you keep a file open in /proc/$pid will Linux avoid reusing that PID?

Until you call one of the wait functions, your children aren't reaped so the PIDs can't be reused. However, you're correct that there's a race condition in general.

The same problem would exist if there were a system call rather than reading a file. There's no "locking" mechanism for PIDs.

Similar problems exist with PID files in /var/run. If the process crashes so it can't remove its PID file, the PID may be reused.

There isn't really any way to prevent these races. But PIDs aren't reused right away, because it needs to cycle through the full PID space. And when it's reused, it will probably have a different uid, so unless the killing process is running as root it won't be able to kill it.

By default there are 2^15 PIDs. This means that in most circumstances need to create and destroy thousands or millions of processes per second to notice the problem. (As the other comment says, there is no problem with your own children to begin with, as they are only reaped when you allow that).

The only truly race free ways to avoid PID races on Linux is to either use containers (which requires root or user namespaces) or use pidfd (which rules out using things like shell). There's a good summary of the issues around trying to kill child processes on https://catern.com/process.html .

Ah fantastic link @Anon. Looks like pidfd is the answer. I'm glad I wasn't the only one who thought the PID system was crazy!
